# How can I catch an exception when I use motor to insert data?

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, tornado, tornado-motor

```
#some code

@tornado.gen.engine
def do_insert():
    result = yield motor.Op(db.test_collection.insert, {'_id': 1})

try:
    do_insert()
except:
    print "error"

#some code
```

I tried code like this. The database is mongodb.
The first time I run it, it insert data correctly.
The second time I run it, it should have an exception and print "error". But it crashed instead of print "error".

Answer (score 1):

`do_insert` is an *asynchronous* function; this means that calling it starts some task, but it doesn't finish immediately, and it probably isn't finished by the time it returns.  To see the result (if it returned anything) or the exception (if it fails), you have to wait for it to finish.  This generally means you need a "yield" at the call site as well (and so on all the way up the stack).  At the top level you need to run an IOLoop:  in a batch-style application you'll probably want to use IOLoop.run_sync; in a long-running server you'll use IOLoop.start instead.  Your example would be (note the use of gen.coroutine instead of gen.engine; this works better with run_sync):

```
@tornado.gen.coroutine
def do_insert():
    result = yield motor.Op(db.test_collection.insert, {'_id': 1})

try:
    IOLoop.instance().run_sync(do_insert())
except:
    print "error"
```

Answer (score 0):

I catch the error within the wrapped inserting method and it works for me:

```
@tornado.gen.engine
def do_insert():
    try:
        result = yield motor.Op(db.test_collection.insert, {'_id': 1})
    except:
        <you should log here>
```